# Сортировка массива на основе значений из другого массива

Tags: javascript

Есть два массива:

```
let name = ["colin", "amandba", "amandab", "carol", "paul", "joseph"]
let rang = [58, 172, 172, 270, 108, 79]
```

Значение из массива name соответствует значению массива rang по индексу (например, colin = 58, amandba = 172 и т.д.)

Необходимо отсортировать массив name на основе значений из массива rang (в порядке убывания - от большего rang к меньшему rang)

Если значения в массиве name имеют одинаковые значения в rang (amandba = 172 и amandab = 172) - такие значения нужно отсортировать в алфавитном порядке)

Должно получиться:

```
["carol", "amandab", "amandba", "paul", "joseph", "colin"]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такую сортировку.

Comment: если _от меньшего rang к большему rang_ - то как получилось `"carol", "amandab", "amandba", "paul", "joseph", "colin"]`, если `colin = 58` ?

Comment: Не так написал, наоборот - от большего к меньшему (то есть в начале самое большое, в конце самое маленькое)

Comment: отредактируй вопрос так, чтобы правильно было

Comment: гарантируется, что каждому элементу в rang соответствует элемент из name?

Comment: Да, оба массива всегда одинаковой длинны и значения первого массива всегда соответствуют значению второго массива по индексу.

Answer (score 1):

Задача сводится к двум действиям:

1. получить словарь, где ключом будет слово, и значением `rang`. Для этого можно воспользоваться методом `.reduce`:

   ```
   var map = name.reduce((acc, cur, index)=>{
       acc[cur] = rang[index];
       return acc;
   },{});
   ```
2. отсортировать массив, проверяя значения из словаря и в случае их равенства сравнивая строки:

   ```
   var sorted = name.sort((a,b)=>{
       var rangA = map[a];
       var rangB = map[b];

       if (rangA != rangB) return rangB-rangA; // сравниваем ранг

       // сравниваем строки
       if (a < b) return 1;
       if (a > b) return -1;
       return 0;
   })
   ```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А есть какой-то способ сортировки данных значений с помощью метода .indexOf? То есть чтобы можно было отсортировать с меньшим кол-вом действий.

Comment: @Vitaliy, в ответе - минимальное количество действий. Используя indexOf - сложность сильно возрастает, как раз за счет длительного поиска ранга для элемента

Comment: Понял, спасибо.